# Is it possible to decline a received bank transfer?

Tags: bank-account, money-transfer, ukraine

If I received a payment I haven't expected, could I decline it so the money would be returned back to the account they were transferred from? I'm in Ukraine if it makes a difference.

Comment: I'm located in Ukraine. The bank in question is a member of OTP Bank Group to not dive much into personal details. Also I'm curious if that's possible in banking systems in general.

Comment: I don't know about Ukraine specifically, but in general, yes, it *should* be possible to reject a deposit, but you would have to get in touch with your bank to do so. It's *almost assuredly* better than sending the money somewhere else yourself, as many scammers would want you to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could I decline it so the money would be returned back to the account they were transferred from?

As a general banking practise, there is nothing automated that will allow you to mark something as return the funds.

You would have to approach your Bank with a written statement mentioning that you don't recognise this credit as belonging to you and request the bank to take appropriate action.